# Return to normal terminal view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I seem to have split my terminal and I can't figure out how to get back to the normal view.

Here is what my vscode looks like right now:

[image]

I basically want to get back to the view where I have a single terminal without the debug console. Could someone please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: try on title bar of panel: Right-click | Reset Location. Panels and views are now Drag-Drop

Comment: Thanks! I was clicking like a madman but this seems to have fixed it!